Finding Python Errors - Async function not Awaited
I am using Python in Visual Studio 2022 - not Code, on Win11.  I had a bug recently where an async function was not awaited. It occurred to me that it would be great to find these types of errors at design time, not run time.
I have tried installing PyLint, but none of the PyLint options are available in the Tools Menu.  I have Python installed as a workload in VS 2022.
Can anyone tell me how to get VS2022 set up so that I can trap async functions that are called without an await prefix?

please, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . also, does this 'bug' exhibit outside of VS2022?
